# How to disable the Superfish Accordion?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

Is it possible to disable the superfish accordion 'main menu' link at the smaller responsive sizes? Instead of clicking on 'main menu' to see the navigation, I would like the navigation to already be expanded without having to click on a link. The navigation should go from the horizontal menu directly to the vertical menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my superfish navigation block, under superfish settings, set the style of the superfish menu to none and under superfish plugins, disabled sf-Touchscreen.

In my main stylesheet I defined the menu style I wanted at the smaller size.